# What does the "Type" Keyword in CUPS printers.conf mean?

Tags: printing, cups

After installing *cups-pdf* on Debian I recognized
a `Type 8450124` for the new printer in *printers.conf*.
Other printers have `Type 4`. So I was curious what this keyword means,
but I couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: Hm... I would bet it's a bitmapped value. Maybe for accepted mime-types or other printer attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Source, Luke..

https://github.com/apple/cups/blob/v2.2.1/cups/cups.h#L201

(for CUPS 2.2.1 distributed in Debian Jessie)

short answer: it's a bitmapped value for various printer attributes, like "local/remote", "color/bw", ...